# Unity 3D spawning a prefab from a List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script where it loads the prefabs from my Resources/ai folder and loop up to five times and generate a random index number. It successfully loaded my prefabs as GameObjects and does generate random index based on the count of the List.

However, I am having trouble upon spawning my prefab to my scene since Instatiate command does return an error while I'm coding.

I have tried methods to grab the name of the prefab through `list[index].name` or even `list[index].toString()` but it wont work. (Note: `list` stands for a variable of a list `index` is just an index to grab the game object on the list. This is not the actual code).

How to spawn a loaded GameObject prefab to my scene with a list?

My current code:

```
public List<GameObject> ai;
public GameObject[] spawn;

int indexAI;
int indexSpawn;

private void Start()
{
    var res = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("ai/");

    foreach (GameObject obj in res)
    {
        ai.Add(obj);
    }


    for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        indexAI = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,ai.Count);
        indexSpawn = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, spawn.Length);

        string name = ai[indexAI].name;
        Debug.Log(name);

        //I am currently using this kind of format since this is what I know for now.
        Instantiate(name,spawn[indexSpawn].transform.position,spawn[indexSpawn].transform.rotation);
    }
```

[The error looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIGQ2.png)

Thanks!

Comment: what error is it returning? Please post that as well as your `instantiate` code

Comment: What is `ai` (how is it defined)?

Comment: @UnholySheep `List<GameObject> ai`. You can tell by by looking at `ai.Count` and `ai.Add(obj);`. @OP Your question is not clear and you are not even instantiating anything.

Comment: @Programmer it might just as well be `List<Object>` or `ArrayList` or a bunch of other containers (or even something custom that just happens to implement the `Count` property and `Add` method) - IMO it's a rather important detail to know

Comment: @Programmer my apologies, I just reverted that not to instantiate things. I'm gonna update the code a bit.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: See ryemoss' answer. That will likely fix your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to instantiate a string - you need to instantiate the gameobject in your ai list instead.

```
Instantiate(ai[indexAI] ,spawn[indexSpawn].transform.position, spawn[indexSpawn].transform.rotation);
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to spawn my prefabs. I just don't know the proper format since I thought it needs a string to spawn prefabs. My bad but thanks a lot!